# Is it possible to declare multiple variables inside of a loop based on a count?

Tags: java

Let's say I wanted to declare an amount of variables inside of a loop based on a count.

```
private static void declaration(int amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= amount; i++)
    {
        /*Code that declares variables.
         *
         *When i == 0, it will declare int num0 with a value of 0.
         *When i == 1, it will declare int num1 with a value of 0, etc.
         */
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do inside of Java?

Comment: Yes. If you use an array.

Comment: You should probably go with some collection data-type: an array or a list. Java does not allow to dynamically create attributes by name like e.g. Python.

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, you'll need some kind of data structure, e.g. a List, Map etc.

e.g. if they need to be identified by name

```
Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
    variables.put("num" + i, 0);
}
// latter get value
System.out.println(variables.get("num3"));
```

e.g. if only index matters

```
int[] state = new int[amount];
for (int i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
    state[i] = 0; // <== all elements are already zero, but just to show you idea
}
```